# Explain some knockout code

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'editFile', 'if': fileToEdit, data: fileToEdit },myDialog: { open: fileToEdit, accept: acceptFile, cancel: cancelFile, position: $root.lastClicked }">
</div>
```

how is 'fileToEdit' invoked ?
I think 'myDialog' is a custom template ? This looks to be invoked by this code :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myDialog
```

Is this iniitialising any custom bindings for 'myDialog' ?

knockout provides documentation for some of the parameters :

> name — the ID of an element that contains the template you wish to
>   render - see Note 5 for how to vary this programmatically. data — an
>   object to supply as the data for the template to render. If you omit
>   this parameter, KO will look for a foreach parameter, or will fall
>   back on using your current model object. if — if this parameter is
>   provided, the template will only be rendered if the specified
>   expression evaluates to true (or a true-ish value). This can be useful
>   for preventing a null observable from being bound against a template
>   before it is populated. foreach — instructs KO to render the template
>   in “foreach” mode - see Note 2 for details. as — when used in
>   conjunction with foreach, defines an alias for each item being
>   rendered - see Note 3 for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at knockout template [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html). As I understand the template will be rendered if 'fileToEdit' variable is not null.

'myDialog' [is custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). It will be initialized as soon as div will be created.